# Angular Material - How to use all colors in HTML of active theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I import the SCSS theming functions to my component's stylesheet:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import 'src/my-mat-color-palette';
```

I can access all theme colors / hues like this:

```css
background: mat-color($my-pallete, 700);
color: mat-contrast($my-pallete, 700);
```

In template file I am also able to set `primary`, `accent` and `warn` theme color for components that have the `@Input() color` property:

```html
<button mat-button color="accent">Click me!</button>
```

But how can I set all the other colors / hues in template file? Are they already provided as classes (something like `mat-primary-300`) or do I have to declare them myself?

Answer (score 6):

As of now, there isn't any direct way in material 2 (like md-color in angular material) to use hues, however you can use following work around:
Create style classes as follows:

```
.primary-light-bg {
  background-color: mat-color($primary, lighter);
}

.primary-dark-bg {
  background-color: mat-color($primary, darker);
}

.primary-bg-A200 {
  background-color: mat-color($primary, A200);
}

.primary-bg-A300 {
  background-color: mat-color($primary, A400);
}
```

You can also use other color swatches.
For e.g.:

```
.purple-bg-600 {
  background: mat-color($mat-purple, 600);
}

.green-bg-600 {
  background: mat-color($mat-green, 600);
}
```

Hope this helps!